# widen space between words in gb4e

Tags: spacing, linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I use the [`gb4e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) package for writing linguistics examples. A MWE is something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll aaaaa bbbbbb cccc\\
 gloss gloss gloss\\
 \glt `translation'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, the space between the aligned items, e.g., between `aaaaa` and `bbbbbb` looks very small to my eyes, especially when the example sentence is long and complex. Is there a way to widen it (or control its width)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the length of the `\glossglue`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\setlength{\glossglue}{3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\begin{document}

3 point

\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll aaaaa bbbbbb cccc\\
 gloss gloss gloss\\
 \glt `translation'
\end{exe}

\setlength{\glossglue}{5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}

5 point

\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll aaaaa bbbbbb cccc\\
 gloss gloss gloss\\
 \glt `translation'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

The default is `0pt plus 2pt minus 1pt`; set the first value to something bigger as in my example. You may want to go as big as 5pt.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I have encountered a new issue, however. That is, since I widened the spaces in between items, long examples are now two-lines, and it seems like right-justification is on and consequently widens the spaces to unwanted wide width. Is there a way to turn right-justification off or simply place a break (into a new line, like CR?) where I'd like the first line to end? (If I need to make this into a new question, rather than this comment, please let me know.) Thanks so much!

Comment: @renoh I can't seem to reproduce your problem (by adding some long examples to my minimal document) so there must be something else you are doing with your code. It might make sense to ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. OK, I'll try to figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this tip. Do you know a way to do the exact same thing under package PHILEX ? Thank you !

Comment: @Neige Since `philex` loads `cgloss4e` to do glosses, the same solution works with `philex` too.